# How can I evaluate a function using the results of Reduce?

Tags: equation-solving, variable

Can I use the output of reduce to define a variable in a function definition? In other words, can I somehow skip the step where I manually enter t:=2?

```
Reduce[{-2 + t == 0,3 t == 6,4 + t == 6},t]
t==2
t := 2
f[x_, y_, z_] = {-2 + t, 3 t, 4 + t}
{0, 6, 6}
```

I tried ./ and ToRule, neither seem to work

Comment: `ClearAll[t]; sol = ToRules@Reduce[{-2 + t == 0, 3 t == 6, 4 + t == 6}, t];`

Comment: that's... interesting. I wish there was some less convoluted technique, but if y'all decide which one of you wants to write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[t]; t=t/.ToRules[Reduce[{-2 + t == 0,3 t == 6,4 + t == 6},t]]
```